# Bike size - will a 2cm make a difference

Tags: frames

I am buying a Cannondale Synapse 105. I have to buy used, not new.  There are two I am considering, they are identical except one is 54 cm and the other is 56 cm. My height is 5' 10/11".  I have read many articles on bike size.  Are there any experienced bikers here who can offer good guidance?

Comment: The best thing is to ride them and see which one fits you best.  Not just a sit-on, a good ride, with some flat, and an uphill and downhill grade.  Your height is only part of the question - what's your inseam length?  (crotch to floor while standing)

Comment: Two riders may be of the same height but still have different lengths for legs and upper body. Then, some riders might prefer a smaller size because the frame is stiffer.

Comment: 2cm will make a difference, but there is no telling which one would suit you best since it depends on your body proportions, flexibility, riding style ... etc.

Comment: Do you have a bike already? If so, you could work out the stack & reach of your existing bike and see how it compares to the two Cannondales to work out which would be a better fit.

Answer (score 5):

Many people fall between two sizes and can get a smaller size or larger size to work, possibly with a few adjustments/parts (e.g. new stem, etc.).

You really have to try the bike to find out. I happen to be 5'11" as well, and my neighbor (who is also 5'11") did own a Synapse 105 (a few years ago; doubt its the same bike still) 56 cm and found it fine but on the bigger side. I found it a bit small when I tried it.

Depends on the rider -- there is no way to find out otherwise without trying them.

Comment: Brilliant advice there. Everyone is different and even if your friend is the same size as you, your preference may be different